# How to get Table field names at top of result array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Here is my **Sample table**:

[image]

Here is My **Query**:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

**Result** for above query is:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => a
                [country] => x
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => b
                [country] => y
            )
    )
```

I need to get the field names in the first element of the array.

**Expected result array** is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => id
            [name] => name
            [country] => country
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => a
            [country] => x
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => b
            [country] => y
        )
)
```

How can I modify the **Query** to get this result?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display issues should generally be dealt with in application code, not SQL queries. If you have your values in an array (called `$results`, say), you can use this code to add the desired entry:

```
array_unshift($results, array_combine(array_keys($results[0]), array_keys($results[0])));
print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => id
            [name] => name
            [country] => country
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => a
            [country] => x
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => b
            [country] => y
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/h3pIH)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'id' id, 'name' name, 'country' country
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, country FROM table
ORDER BY 'id' != id
```

Comment: This is a dangerous practice as it forces type conversion of the actual table values to strings, which may yield unexpected results.

Comment: @Nick No way - the task NEEDS in type convertion because desired 1st record has string datatype for all columns. The only solution avoided type convertion is to realize this task on the client side. But OP says "Help me How to modify **Query**..."

Comment: We can choose to take a more holistic approach to solving problems. Sometimes, the literal approach does more harm than good.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [array_unshift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php). If I were you I will get the SQL result as `$array` variable and do some processing on `php` side like below on query side.

```
<?php
$array = [['id'=>1,'name'=>'a','country'=>'x'],['id'=>1,'name'=>'b','country'=>'y']];
$keys = array_keys($array[0]);
$first = array_combine($keys,$keys);
array_unshift($array,$first);
print_r($array);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/IqZVk

Comment: this is exactly the same as my answer

Comment: @Nick Yes, it could be sir. When I post my answer and reload the web page then I saw your answer. May I delete mine?